# Syntax weirdness of using keyword

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I thought the keyword `using` was exact as for C++ which was used for `namespaces` but, in the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html), there is this block of code:

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
        int page = pages.Length - 1;

        switch (webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't comprehend what the `using` keyword is doing in here. Could someone please explain this a bit?

Comment: Have you tried reading the official Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) on C#?

Comment: @fredrik , thanks , and I just did read it up. I'm unsure, if this is like contextManagers for python, (that e.g. close file descriptors after a certain block of code)?

Comment: As the documentation says, it's a generic construct to ensure that disposable objects are disposed. This can be files, streams, network sockets, or anything else that has IDisposable (or IAsyncDisposable) implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Unity specific but basic `c#`.

There are different usecases / functionalities for the keyword [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using)

> - **The [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) defines a scope at the end of which an object will be disposed.**
> - The using directive creates an alias for a namespace or imports types defined in other namespaces.
> - The using static directive imports the members of a single class.

Yours is the first case where a `using` **statement** block makes sure that as soon as the block ends the according [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) (or since c# 8 [`IAsyncDispoable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable)) gets called its according [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose#System_IDisposable_Dispose) (or [`DisposeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync#System_IAsyncDisposable_DisposeAsync)) method automatically.

If you look into the [`UnityWebRequest` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/UnityWebRequest/Public/UnityWebRequest.bindings.cs) you can see that it implements

> ```
> public partial class UnityWebRequest : IDisposable
> ```

and in the according [`UnityWebRequest` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Dispose.html) is states

> Signals that this `UnityWebRequest` is no longer being used, and should
> clean up any resources it is using.
>
> You must call `Dispose` once you have finished using a `UnityWebRequest`
> object, regardless of whether the request succeeded or failed.
>
> For safety, it is usually a best practice to employ the [`using`
> statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to ensure that a `UnityWebRequest` is properly cleaned up in
> case of uncaught exceptions.

Which basically brings you to the exact same page as the `using statement` link above ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for a Unity HTTP communication. If a class implements the `IDisposable` interface, it means, it can be used by `using` statement. The statement ensures, that the `Dispose()` method of the class will be called after the body of the `using` statement.

As the documentation says here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

In this example `Dispose()` needs to be called in order to correctly close a network connection.

> `Dispose()`: Signals that this UnityWebRequest is no longer being used, and should clean up any resources it is using.

So `using` does the `Dispose()` calling for you.